# Printing elements from a list of class pointers c++

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to overload the << operator so that it prints out the entire content of a list of class pointers.

Here's what I got:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, listClass &obj){
        list<baseClass*>::iterator it;
        for (it = obj.listB.begin(); it != obj.listB.end(); ++it){
            out << *it << endl;
        }
        return out;
    }
```

I know that if the list was of simple class objects instead of class pointers this code would have worked fine, but as it is now the *it prints the addresses of the list elements. I tried for the life of me to find the answer on google but found nothing.

How do you get the content of a class pointer iterator?

Thank you for your time!

EDIT: Apparently *(*it) yields the right result. Is that correct?

Comment: Dereference the pointer into the object it's pointing at and print whatever member you were after?

Comment: _"Apparently `*(*it)` yields the right result. Is that correct?"_ Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Since `it` is an iterator, `*it` gives you the item at the current iteration.  Since this `*it` is a pointer `baseClass *`, to deference it again (`**it`) gives you the `baseClass` it points to.  Assuming you have an `operator<<()` for `baseClass`, it should work.

Comment: Yup, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Since C++11, there is a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) syntax that could have simplified much of your situation.  You don't have to explicitly mess with iterators.  You could just use `for (baseClass *i : obj) out << *i << endl;`.  Be sure to compile with `-std=c++11` (or later).

Answer (score 0):

A `std::list` iterator *points* to an item in the list.

To access the item, you would *dereference* the pointer:

```
iterator->item;
```

or

```
(*iterator).item;
```

Iterators have a lot in common with pointers.